# how to load status bar after changing initial view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, view

There's a problem with showing my ArticlesViewController. This code works great, but when Articles page appears, there's no status bar.
I think there's something wrong with navigation controller, so i've tried to add

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

both in AppDelegate's **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** and ArticlesViewController's **viewDidLoad** and **viewWillAppear**, but still no results

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
    localStorage = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    NSObject *obj = [localStorage valueForKey:@"isAppLaunchedOnce"];
    NSString *condition = [[[obj description] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSCharacterSet *unwantedChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\"()"];
    condition = [[condition componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unwantedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    if ([condition isEqual: @"YES"]){
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = (ArticlesViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ArticlesViewController"];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1){
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    navController.navigationItem.titleView.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{
    NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]
    };
    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes;
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: If you have a main storyboard why are you creating the nav controller and articles view controller in code?

Comment: @matt As I understood, I don't create ArticlesViewController, i get this controller from storyboard and change then my initialViewController in app. If you think I can use my existing navigation controller - ask me how, it possibly can be an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ArticlesViewController` add the following method give it a try.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}
```

If you have not set in the plist then you need to set for each controller.

You can also set by just adding the below line in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

[image]

[image]

Check these key in the plist file and Set Status bar initial hidden also as NO

Comment: I added this line to my appDelegate and set Status bar to Default, but it doesn't show bar